# Checking sdcard for errors, unmount problem

Tags: debian, hardware, sd-card, mount

I've tried running running a disk check, then I got a complain

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ /sbin/fsck
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
e2fsck 1.42.5 (29-Jul-2012)
/dev/mmcblk0p2 is mounted.

WARNING!!!  The filesystem is mounted.   If you continue you ***WILL***
cause ***SEVERE*** filesystem damage.

Do you really want to continue<n>? no
check aborted.
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ umount -l /dev/mmcblk0p2
umount: it seems /dev/mmcblk0p2 is mounted multiple times
```

**Do I have to umount, what are the steps for a safe umount?**

Update:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ mount
/dev/root on / type ext4 (rw,noatime,nodiratime,user_xattr,barrier=1,data=ordered)
devtmpfs on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,relatime,size=118872k,nr_inodes=29718,mode=755)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=23788k,mode=755)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=47560k)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620)
/dev/mmcblk0p1 on /boot type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=cp437,iocharset=ascii,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)

pi@raspberrypi ~ $ cat /etc/mtab
rootfs / rootfs rw 0 0
/dev/root / ext4 rw,noatime,nodiratime,user_xattr,barrier=1,data=ordered 0 0
devtmpfs /dev devtmpfs rw,relatime,size=118872k,nr_inodes=29718,mode=755 0 0
tmpfs /run tmpfs rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=23788k,mode=755 0 0
tmpfs /run/lock tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k 0 0
proc /proc proc rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
sysfs /sys sysfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
tmpfs /run/shm tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=47560k 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620 0 0
/dev/mmcblk0p1 /boot vfat rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=cp437,iocharset=ascii,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro 0 0

pi@raspberrypi ~ $ cat /etc/fstab
proc            /proc           proc    defaults          0       0
/dev/mmcblk0p1  /boot           vfat    defaults          0       2
/dev/mmcblk0p2  /               ext4    defaults,noatime,nodiratime,nodiratime  0       1
# a swapfile is not a swap partition, so no using swapon|off from here on, use  dphys-swapfile swap[on|off]  for that
```

I also see this in dmesg:

```
[    3.054577] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0: eth0: register 'smsc95xx' at usb-bcm2708_usb-1.1, smsc95xx USB 2.0 Ethernet, b8:27:eb:3a:ff:c1
[    4.592609] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 47900
[    4.611794] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 31567
[    4.630805] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 23732
[    4.647041] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 4871
[    4.662074] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 4653
[    4.662256] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 4514
[    4.662344] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 4465
[    4.677977] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 3989
[    4.678142] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): 8 orphan inodes deleted
[    4.685881] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): recovery complete
[    8.631347] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    8.644244] VFS: Mounted root (ext4 filesystem) on device 179:2.
[    8.654677] devtmpfs: mounted
[    8.661103] Freeing init memory: 124K
[   10.414514] udevd[139]: starting version 175
[   21.263308] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): re-mounted. Opts: (null)
[   21.967590] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): re-mounted. Opts: (null)
[   22.849536] bcm2835 ALSA card created!
[   22.855703] bcm2835 ALSA chip created!
[   22.875121] bcm2835 ALSA chip created!
[   22.885884] bcm2835 ALSA chip created!
[   22.894074] bcm2835 ALSA chip created!
[   22.902271] bcm2835 ALSA chip created!
[   22.910319] bcm2835 ALSA chip created!
[   22.918129] bcm2835 ALSA chip created!
```

Comment: Please run mount with no arguements and post the output.

Comment: @AlexChamberlain See my updated with the contents of the mounts.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

/dev/mmcblk0p2 is the root file system, so it is not easily unmounted. It could probably be re-mounted as read-only, but a simpler way is to schedule a fsck at the next reboot.

> sudo touch /forcefsck

then reboot. Or reboot with

> shutdown -rF now

which does the same.
(from https://superuser.com/questions/401217/how-to-check-root-partition-with-fsck)

Another option of course is to do the fsck on another linux computer with a card reader.

Answer (score 2):

sudo touch /forcesck didn't work for me...

but I did the following and it checked errors:

force a manual fsck and reboot:

```
 fsck -fy /dev/mmcblk0p2
```

```
 reboot
```

Comment: where did you get `/dev/mmcblk0p2 ` How can I figure out myself?

Comment: @Pentium10 `df`

Comment: The `df` command did not work for me to detect the root partition on Kali Linux v2.0. I solved it by issuing `mount` and checking for the `/` mount, or `mount | grep " / "` (note the existing ` ` spaces).

Comment: I don't think forcing `fsck` on a mounted root partition would be a good idea.

Comment: you have a typo. it's "forcefsck" and not "forcesck"

Comment: @Pentium10 `lsblk` will do that

Answer (score 2):

The [**bottom line**](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/bottom+line) with `fsck` is this:

***You should not run `fsck` on a mounted filesystem***

If you need to run `fsck` on your RPi's root filesystem/SD card, there are two choices:

### 1. Remove the SD card media from the RPi

This approach will be most useful for SD cards (or other media in general) that are **suspected** of being bad/faulty. It may even prove useful in *salvaging* boot media with the repair (`-p`) option.

**Note:** You'll need the following items to use this procedure:

- USB-to-SD adapter - Something like **this**:

[image]

- A Linux PC - or another RPi - something running a fairly current version of the OS
- ***As an alternative to a 2nd RPi or Linux PC, you can simply boot your RPi from a spare SD card!***

#### Step 1:

After removing power from the RPi, remove the SD card to be checked & repaired from its slot, and insert it into the **USB-to-SD adapter**

#### Step 2:

Insert the USB-to-SD adapter into an available USB port on a laptop or RPi.

#### Step 3:

From a terminal window on the Linux PC/RPi, use `lsblk` to get the necessary file system "handles" for the SD card:

```bsh
$ lsblk --fs
```

You should see something like this:

```
NAME        FSTYPE LABEL       UUID                                 FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINT
sda
└─sda1      ext4   PASSPORT2TB 86645948-d127-4991-888c-a466b7722f05    1.5T    11% /mnt/Passport2TB
sdc
├─sdc1      vfat   boot        592B-C92C
└─sdc2      ext4   rootfs      706944a6-7d0f-4a45-9f8c-7fb07375e9f7
mmcblk0
├─mmcblk0p1 vfat               6969-16D1                             200.4M    22% /boot
└─mmcblk0p2 ext4               f6ea6ef9-68be-479d-b447-5f76391cc02f     23G    16% /
```

`sda` is a **mounted** USB drive I have named `Passport2TB`

`mmcblk0` is my RPi's SD card - the one it is currently running - **not** the **suspect** SD card

And finally,

`sdc` is the **USB-to-SD adapter** with the **suspect** SD card

Note that there are two partitions in `sdc`: one `vfat`, one `ext4` as `sdc1` and `sdc2` respectively. Also note that the `MOUNTPOINT` column shows **both partitions are unmounted**, and therefore safe to be `fsck'd` :)

And so, we are now ready to `fsck`...

#### Step 4:

As it turns out, the `fsck` command falls into a rather large class of Linux commands that have been *extended* and upgraded to support the relentless advance of technology. That is, `fsck` is now a **wrapper** or a **front-end** for a host of *underling commands* that do the actual work. Without wandering too far afield with the details of this *evolution* of `fsck`, let me just say that `man fsck` lists the *underlings* we need:

- `e2fsck`:  check a Linux ext2/ext3/ext4 file system; ref `man e2fsck`
- `fsck.vfat`: check and repair MS-DOS filesystems; ref `man fsck.vfat`

Tools in hand, we may finally get to the task.  ***Using the filesystem handles from above***:

```bsh
$  $ sudo e2fsck -p /dev/sdc2
rootfs: clean, 45989/1899328 files, 524782/7725184 blocks
```

Unfortunately (for purposes of this example), the `ext4` partition on my SD card was `clean` - no errors. The response would have been different of course had there been issues, and of course dependent upon what those issues are. Next up, the `vfat` partition - which contains the `boot` files:

```bsh
$ sudo fsck.vfat -p /dev/sdc1
fsck.fat 4.1 (2017-01-24)
/dev/sdc1: 321 files, 111913/516190 clusters
```

Not as affirmative as `e2fsck`, but the message is the same: it found no problems with the `vfat` partition.

#### Step 5:

`fsck` found no errors... what does this mean?

It *probably* means that whatever errors you experienced were not in the *filesystem*. It *probably* means that your SD card is still viable, and can be used again. You should *probably* re-flash it to remove any corrupted files & ensure all required files are present.

### 2. Run it during the `boot` process - which happens before it's mounted

[This is covered under another answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/116571/83790), so I'll not repeat it here.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue when using putty to connect to my pi.
I assume you are using some remote connect like putty.
Try hooking your RPi HDMI directly to a monitor, plugging a usb keyboard into your RPi then powering up. Watch the screen for errors then run `fsck` when boot complete.