# Output fsck on boot to a log file

Tags: boot, pi-3b+, logfiles, fsck

I'd like to use `fsck` on every boot of my RPi 3B+ server. To do this I will be using `tune2fs -c 1 /dev/mmcblk0p2`. When `fsck` runs I'd like the output to be added to a log file in `/home/pi/fsck.log` with the date and time above it, for example,

```
04/19/20 14:00
(fsck log)
```

How would I configure the RPi to do this?

Comment: Why not just use the redirect as normal `>` or `>>` when you run fsck or am I missing something?  Also is this on an SD card or HDD / SSD and why are you doing it?

Comment: SD card. I'm doing it so I can track FS errors and replace the SD card if needed. WDYM by 'redirect as normal when you run fsck', if it's automatically running at boot how could I do this?

Comment: I had assumed you where controlling when fschk runs.  File system errors can occur for many reasons other than the SD card failing.  The SD cards I have had fail in cameras just go write only - other file system errors are normally due to me pulling the wrong plug (solved by colour coded cases and a silver sharpie now).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no need to run `tune2fs -c 1 /dev/mmcblk0p2` to run `fsck`. As you are not "tuning" any fs parameters, using `tune2fs` as a proxy for `fsck` simply adds overhead & may slow the boot process by a small amount.

As strictly a fine point, I don't think that `tune2fs` runs `fsck` at all - it runs `e2fsck`. In current versions of the OS, `fsck` serves as a *"wrapper"* or *"front-end"* to provide *legacy* support. Typically, `fsck` simply calls `e2fsck` to do the real work. Note also that while using the plain `fsck` will get the job done in *most cases*, it may not be capable of passing *options* you wish to use with `e2fsck`.

That said, here's a **recommended** way to run `fsck` on every boot:

#### Use your editor to add the following to `/boot/cmdline.txt` (recommended):

> fsck.mode=force

```
$ nano /boot/cmdline.txt
...
 
# FROM:  
console=serial0,115200 console=tty1 root=PARTUUID=6c586e13-02 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait  

# TO:  
console=serial0,115200 console=tty1 root=PARTUUID=6c586e13-02 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.mode=force fsck.repair=yes rootwait
```

#### Other methods to run `fsck` at boot (not recommended):

You can also use the *legacy* technique of creating a file named `forcefsck` in the root of the filesystem `/`; i.e. `sudo touch forcefsck`. However, this may be ill-advised:

- the file `/forcefsck` is removed before booting is completed - which means you'll need to automate adding it (e.g. a `cron @reboot job`) following each reboot.
- a warning to use the method above (`fsck.mode=force`) will be issued by `systemd` to `var/log/syslog`:

> Please pass 'fsck.mode=force' on the kernel command line rather than creating /forcefsck on the root file system.

#### logging `fsck` results to /home/pi/fsck.log

`fsck` results are logged to `var/log/syslog` by default. Rather than trying to redirect or duplicate those log entries to another file, I'd suggest the following:

```
$ less /var/log/syslog
```

This will load the log into the `less` [pager](https://www.slackbook.org/html/file-commands-pagers.html). Once the logfile is loaded, search and highlight all instances of `fsck` by entering `/fsck`. You may now scroll through the logfile, and your attention will be drawn to each highlighted entry for `fsck`. This has the advantage of seeing potentially relevant events which are not generated by `fsck`.

As an alternative to the above, if you strictly want to see log entries generated by `fsck`, `journalctl` is a friend:

```
$ journalctl -u systemd-fsck*
```