# Disk access seems slow?

Tags: raspbian, sd-card, readwrite

My system seems SLOW.

In addition, I've suffered file corruption, both to my FAT32 /boot/ and to the ext3 partition.

I haven't a clue why it might be slow as the SD card is a quality Phillips card very recently (within last fortnight) imaged and verified with Etcher.

How can I check if (somehow) the SD card is going or gone?

I had to write over the files on /boot/ with fresh copies to even get the Pi to boot today.

Are some SD cards just kind of - only half good?!

I'm surprised a branded card is giving me these issues.

Answer (score 3):

The only check I know of is `fsck`, and its *underlings* `e2fsck` and `fsck.vfat`. A recent answer here provided a [*step-by-step* procedure](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/119811/83790) for this.

There's another utility that may be useful for checking the **speed**: It's called `agnostics`, and is available through RPi's `apt` repository:

```bash
$ sudo apt-get update
...
$ sudo apt-get upgrade 
...
$ sudo apt-get install agnostics
...
```

There was an [article on the RPi website](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/sd-card-speed-test/) about it recently.

Comment: `hdparm -Tt /dev/<disk>` will also run a nice speed test.