# system won't fully boot - “failed to start dhcpcd on all interfaces” and failed to start openbsd secure shell server

Tags: sd-card, corrupt

It also says failed to start "enable compressed swap in memory using zram".

Any ideas why my system keeps getting corrupted?

Sorry - ideally any ideas how I can repair/restore?!

Thanks

Comment: Which OS? Which Pi? What power supply? Using sd card? Any reason you can't just flash a new OS?

Answer (score 1):

Your question lacks detail, but two possibilities come to mind:

1. You have made ill-advised changes to various *configuration files* and/or your system configuration, or
2. Your SD card is failing.

If it's # 1, you should re-install your OS, and start over.

If it's not - if you haven't made changes, then you could check & repair the filesystem using `fsck` - [here's one procedure for that.](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/119811/83790)

If `fsck` finds nothing, there are some other things to try, but it would be best to have a bit more information first.

Finally, and for the longer term: Get (and keep) a spare SD card, and maintain backups of your system.